# Force HTTPS and Avoid 302 Redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-status-code-302

I want to force HTTPS in my site and avoid Redirect 302 in RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%  !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have understood that if I use **https://** it triggers the redirect but then, How I can force to use HTTPS to keep security protocol?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mysite.com

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%  !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```